# Implementing and applying image degradation function to Python

Tags: python, image-processing, filtering, fft

I've been trying to follow an example procedure in the book "Digital Image Processing" (Gonzales and Woods). The procedure is to degrade and blur the image by taking the Fourier Transform of it and multiplying it with H(u,v), and finally doing the Inverse Fourier Transform.

[formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xD3Ed.png)

This is what I've got so far:

```
from __future__ import division
import cv2
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import math
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

img = cv2.imread('book_cover.jpg')
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

xSize, ySize = gray_img.shape


def applyFilter(img, func):
    image = np.copy(img)

    # Construct image from blurring function
    for u in xrange(0,ySize):
        for v in xrange(0,xSize):
            image[u,v] = func(u,v)

    # Performe the actual blurring of the image. Not working as expected
    return image*img

def blurr(y,x):
    a = 0.05
    b = 0.05
    T = 1
    C = math.pi*(a*y+b*x)

    if(C == 0):
        return 1

    return (T/C)*math.sin(C)*math.e**(-1j*C)

def toReal(img):
    realImg = np.zeros(img.shape)

    for i in xrange(0,img.shape[0]):
        for j in xrange(0,img.shape[1]):
            realImg[i,j] = np.absolute(img[i,j])

    return realImg
def normalize(image):
    img = image.copy()
    img = toReal(img)
    img -= img.min()
    img *= 255.0/img.max()
    return img.astype(np.uint8)

f = np.fft.fft2(gray_img.astype(np.int32))
fft_img = np.fft.fftshift(f)

# Apply the blurring filter
filtered_fft = applyFilter(fft_img, blurr)

f_fft_img = np.fft.ifftshift(filtered_fft)
filtered_img = np.fft.ifft2(f_fft_img)

filtered_img = normalize(filtered_img)


cv2.imwrite('book_cover_blurred.jpg', filtered_img.astype(np.uint8))
```

The two book covers on the left are taken from the book, the leftmost being the original image, and the middle one being filtered. The one on the far right is the result I got with the code above.
[Link to images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1qL4.jpg)

I've surely misunderstood something, but I'm at a complete loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the error I made in the end. I made a silly mistake by implementing H(u,v) instead of the correct H(u-M/2,v-N/2).